# MDX year to date comparison Ordering

Tags: mdx

Im am very new to MDX, and cannot work out how to order the following MDX query...

```
WITH 
MEMBER Measures.YTD2010 as 'Aggregate(YTD(Date.CurrentMember), Measures.Value)' 
MEMBER Measures.YTD2009 as 'Aggregate(YTD(ParallelPeriod(Date.Year, 1, Date.CurrentMember)), Measures.Value)' 

SELECT { 
[Measures].YTD2009, 
[Measures].YTD2010 
} ON COLUMNS, 

Order({ [Entity].[Name].Members }, [Measures].YTD2010, DESC) ON ROWS 
FROM [Carbon] 
WHERE [Date].[Year].[2010]
```

As you can see i want to order the measure 'YTD2010'

any help much appreciated.

Comment: Is your query not executing or does it execute and just doesn't order?  Off hand the syntax seems OK.

Comment: its executing and getting the correct data, just not paying any attention to the ordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your order to the following:

```
Order({ [Entity].[Name].Members }, [Measures].YTD2010, BDESC) ON ROWS
```

The difference is BDESC instead of DESC.  BDESC tells it to break the hierarchy.